# Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, console.writeline

In a J2EE application (like one running in WebSphere), when I use `System.out.println()`, my text goes to standard out, which is mapped to a file by the WebSphere admin console.

In an ASP.NET application (like one running in IIS), where does the output of `Console.WriteLine()` go?  The IIS process must have a stdin, stdout and stderr; but is stdout mapped to the Windows version of /dev/null or am I missing a key concept here?

I'm **not asking** if I should log there (I use log4net), but where does the output go?  My best info came from this [discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t91075-where-does-consolewriteline-goto.html) where they say `Console.SetOut()` can change the `TextWriter`, but it still didn't answer the question on what the initial value of the Console is, or how to set it in config/outside of runtime code.

Comment: It would actually go to the STDOUT of the ASP.NET Worker process. Where that is pointed to, I'm not sure.

Comment: That's the question - where does STDOUT go?

Comment: apparently no one knows, but everyone uses it in their examples. wtf

Comment: if you were looking for debugging purposes i would refer the @Greg Bernhardt reply below.

Comment: @KevinHakanson FWIW all these years later, stdout for any process is chosen by its parent, the process which started it. In this case, the parent would be IIS. [This might point you in the right direction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log).

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If you look at the `Console` class in [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector), you'll find that if a process doesn't have an associated console, `Console.Out` and `Console.Error` are backed by `Stream.Null` (wrapped inside a `TextWriter`), which is a dummy implementation of `Stream` that basically ignores all input, and gives no output.

So it is conceptually equivalent to `/dev/null`, but the implementation is more streamlined: there's no actual I/O taking place with the null device.

Also, apart from calling `SetOut`, there is no way to configure the default.

**Update 2020-11-02**: As this answer is still gathering votes in 2020, it should probably be noted that under ASP.NET Core, there usually *is* a console attached. You can configure the [ASP.NET Core IIS Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module) to redirect all stdout and stderr output to a log file via the `stdoutLogEnabled` and `stdoutLogFile` settings:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
              arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
              hostingModel="inprocess"
              stdoutLogEnabled="true"
              stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: Use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() if you actually want something to be written to the Output window, which you can view when debugging.

Answer (score 848):

If you use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`, then you can see the results in the **Output** window of Visual Studio.

Comment: One more little hint; if you are printing a formatted string, use Debug.Print instead of Debug.WriteLine to avoid an argument conflict (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/Vsexpressvcs/thread/f27bacd9-8b86-4f65-95ca-8b30c9e2e915).

Comment: Note that the debugger needs to be attached in order for the messages to be shown in the Output window.

Comment: It is useful to use Console.WriteLine if you use the same DLL across both IIS and console apps.  That's how I ended up here ;)

Comment: I can't believe how many upvotes this "answer" got since it does not actually answering a very specific question "where does it go", but instead recommends a code change, completely bypassing the initial question. This would have been much better as a comment to the correct answer, as an alternative for those who are able to make that code change.

Answer (score 30):

I've found this question by trying to change the Log output of the DataContext to the output window. So to anyone else trying to do the same,  what I've done was create this:

```
class DebugTextWriter : System.IO.TextWriter {
   public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count) {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(new String(buffer, index, count));
   }

   public override void Write(string value) {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(value);
   }

   public override Encoding Encoding {
       get { return System.Text.Encoding.Default; }
   }
}
```

Annd after that: dc.Log = new DebugTextWriter() and I can see all the queries in the output window (dc is the DataContext).

Have a look at this for more info: http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

Comment: Why not just use a static wrapper, given that you're wrapping entirely static methods? Why bother extending `TextWriter`?

Comment: You could also use `dc.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);`.

Comment: Application_Start: System.Console.SetOut(new DebugTextWriter());

Comment: Even better, Console.SetOut(new DebugTextWriter());

Answer (score 19):

If you are using IIS Express and launch it via a command prompt, it will leave the [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) window open, and you will see `Console.Write` statements there.

So for example get a command window open and type:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress" /path:C:\Projects\Website1 /port:1655
```

This assumes you have a website directory at C:\Projects\Website1. It will start IIS Express and serve the pages in your website directory. It will leave the command windows open, and you will see output information there.  Let's say you had a file there, default.aspx, with this code in it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Hello!

    <% for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) %>
       <% { Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()); }%>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Arrange your browser and command windows so you can see them both on the screen. Now type into your browser: `http://localhost:1655/`. You will see Hello! on the webpage, but in the command window you will see something like

```
Request started: "GET" http://localhost:1655/
0
1
2
3
4
5
Request ended: http://localhost:1655/default.aspx with HTTP status 200.0
```

I made it simple by having the code in a code block in the markup, but any console statements in your [code-behind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind) or anywhere else in your code will show here as well.

Comment: +1 I always use IIS Express while developing for this reason. The console output is invaluable, used at the back end like the javascript console at the front end. Saves heaps of time debugging, as opposed to using a file-based server log. You don't have to override "friendly" exception handling - keep the nice "oops" browser page, and just output the exception to the console, easy to see.

Answer (score 14):

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...);` gets it into the *Immediate Window* in Visual Studio 2008.

Go to menu *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Immediate*:

[image]

Comment: In my Visual Studio 2012, I followed what you said but the string appeared in the `Output` just besides the `Immediate Window` Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There simply is no console listening by default. Running in debug mode there is a console attached, but in a production environment it is as you suspected, the message just doesn't go anywhere because nothing is listening.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are in a strict console application, I wouldn't use it, because you can't really see it. I would use Trace.WriteLine() for debugging-type information that can be turned on and off in production.

Comment: Yep, here's a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5952w0c.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Try to attach kinda 'backend debugger' to log your msg or data to the console or output window the way we can do in node console.

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message" + variable)` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`

this way you can see the results in Output window aka Console of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The `TraceContext` object in ASP.NET writes to the `DefaultTraceListener` which outputs to the host process’ [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). Rather than using `Console.Write()`, if you use `Trace.Write`, output will go to the standard output of the process.

You could use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object to get the ASP.NET process for your site and monitor standard output using the `OutputDataRecieved` event.

Answer (score 2):

if you happened to use NLog in your ASP.net project, you can add a [Debugger target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Debugger-target):

```
<targets>
    <target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger"
            layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message} "/>
```

and writes logs to this target for the levels you want:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" />
```

now you have console output just like Jetty in "Output" window of VS, and make sure you are running in Debug Mode(F5).

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing for everyone when it comes IISExpress. There is nothing to read console messages. So for example, in the ASPCORE MVC apps it configures using appsettings.json which does nothing if you are using IISExpress.

For right now you can just add loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug); in your Configure section and it will at least show you your logs in the Debug Output window.

Good news CORE 2.0 this will all be changing: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255

Answer (score 0):

Mac, In Debug mode there is a tab for the Output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using console.Writeline did not work for me.

What did help was putting a breakpoint and then running the test on debug.
When it reaches the breakpoint you can observe what is returned.

Answer (score -4):

In an ASP.NET application, I think it goes to the Output or Console window which is visible during debugging.