# Console output from web applications in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, console

How do you debug web applications written in C# in Visual Studio? I'm using Console.WriteLine expecting the text to appear in the Output tab. Like it does when you develop console applications. But for web applications, the console output doesn't show up anywhere.

Comment: This will be shown in browser's console. Install FireBug in FF and you can see the console output. You can also see the console output in Safari and Chrome in their buit-in error console.

Comment: Check out this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Comment: @fardjad: Console.WriteLine shows up in browser's console? Really?

Comment: @spender: I thought Console.WriteLine is similar to console.log in javascript. I'm sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Debug.WriteLine
```

Comment: are you attached to the web process? ie, have you run the web site, or have you manually attached to w3wp?

Comment: It works when I run the app in debug mode in visual studio, but not otherwise. I guess doing that is a solution, but debug mode turns on lots of other "features" i dont want and is annoying to use.

Comment: Create your own logging functionality then, or use `Trace.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

They are two form to write in Console Output for NET applications.

```
Debug.WriteLine()  // See [Microsoft Documentation][1]
Trace.WriteLine()  // See [Microsoft][2] documentation for more information
```

The difference between the two is that Debug only work when the program is in DEBUG mode. 
In the other hand TRACE works always. You can also set different levels of TRACE. See documentation for more information.

I hope that this information help you.