# Console.Write() - Where does this write to, and how to get written data back (in a Web Page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console

I've seen it in many code samples, tutorials and other people's code that I've worked with. I've never really understood (or even learned) why people use `Console.Write(exception.Message);`.

The only reason I can think of is to log the exception for later investigation. So, I thought I'd give it a try, since I have some spare time on my hands, and have tried to find some specific info regarding my questions, but couldn't find it.

If I use `Console.Write(exception.Message);` in an asp.net webpage, where exactly does this go? Where is the "Console" in a web app/site?

And, how do you "see" what you've previously written to the Console?

Comment: I think you can enable to console for debugging purposes

Comment: If you want to do logging, it would probably be much better to use a properly configurable logging framework.

We use NLOG, so I'm going to recommend that. See http://nlog-project.org/

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual studio, for winforms and WPF application it prints to [Output window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx)
For ASP.Net use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` to print to output window

> To open the Output window, on the View menu, click Output.

You may want to see: [Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)