# Console.WriteLine not showing message

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)

I know the delete is occuring has I checked the database

code:

```
    try
    {
        MyCommand.Connection.Open();

        int count = MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete Success!!!");
            //lblMessage.Text = tbTourName.Text + " Deleted!";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Delete!!!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delete Failed coz.. " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        MyCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Does it supposed to show the message on webpage itself?

Regards
Tea

Comment: The answer to your question is at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Comment: are you using a window application?

Comment: Is it common to write code like this in webpages when doing this time of delete, update, etc to databases?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: for testing you can use [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Do devs leave these response.write's in e.g. on the SqlException so if the website is released, a client as an error, he can let the dev know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Console` object does not belong to the page. This would write a line in your `IDE's console`.

If you want to show a message on your web page then the simplest way would be:

```
Response.Write();
```

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net applications, `Console.WriteLine` goes to `output` window of `visual studio`.

For more refer: [Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Console object cannot add a content to the Page.  Instead, drop the asp:label control onto the form and set its Text property to the required status.