# How to Console.Log, Print_R(), Debug.Trace in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

PHP has a function called print_r() and var_dump() that will display all the contents of an item. It makes it very easy to figure out what things are.

**Is there something like that in C#?**

I know there is a `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` in C#, but does this work in the MVC? Can I do some type of `debug.trace()` like flash does into a debug console while I run the application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net#answer-879928

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("blah");
```

and in order to show all variables in the object you would have to override its ToString() method or write a method which returns all the info you need from the object.
i.e.

```
class Blah{

    string mol = "The meaning of life is";
    int a = 42;    

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return String.Format("{0} {1}", mol, a);
    }
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new Blah().ToString());
```

In short there is nothing in built but it can be done.

If you must print ALL the objects info without overriding or adding logic on a class by class level then you are in the realms of reflection to iterate the objects PropertInfo array