# How to show Console.WriteLine output in my browser console or output window?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console.log

I wrote `System.Console.WriteLine("How can I see this debugging information in a browser");` in the  model of my ASP.NET MVC4 project. How can I see this debugging string in the browser console, or at least in Visual Studio?. I can't find it in the output window of Visual Studio. Maybe I need to install some plugin from NuGet?

Comment: if you are in debug mode output window should show it? No?

Comment: @adt No. `Console.WriteLine` will not display in the output window because it is invoked by the Browser in ASP.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(...)` will not be displayed. If you absolutely need to see output in the debugger, you'll have to use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This will be displayed in output window");
```

and view it in the **Output** window. You can open the output window by going to `Debug -> Window -> Output`:

[image]

Here's an example of what this will all look like:

[image]

For further readings, [check out this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 24):

You can write to your JavaScript console from your C# Code using the following class

```cs
using System.Web;

public static class JavaScript
{
    static string scriptTag = "<script type=\"\" language=\"\">{0}</script>";
    public static void ConsoleLog(string message)
    {       
        string function = "console.log('{0}');";
        string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
    }

    public static void Alert(string message)
    {
        string function = "alert('{0}');";
        string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
    }

    static string GenerateCodeFromFunction(string function)
    {
        return string.Format(scriptTag, function);
    }
}
```

Works just like its JS version; it actually converts your message to JS and injects it into the page.

Comment: I kept getting a "Newline in Constant" error, until I changed the scriptTag declaration to `static string scriptTag = "<script type=\"\" language=\"\">{0}</" + "script>";`

Comment: I get this error: 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Debug.Writeline("debug information")`. It will be displayed in the Output window.

Comment: @Burgi It was also written and posted *before* the accepted answer was.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Sam's answer, you may find [`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx) useful. In some situations - for example, when you are supporting legacy inline .aspx pages - it's more convenient to debug by writing out suspect values to the browser:

```
String myString = GetAStringFromSomewhere();

/* What did that method actually return, anyway?
   NB: Remove this once I know! */
Response.Write(myString);
```

This is less practical in ASP.Net MVC, however, as your controllers will be compiled. In this case, you might as well be writing out your debugging information to a log file, using something like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Answer (score 1):

I have enhanced [MichaelTaylor3D's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713782/how-to-show-console-writeline-output-in-my-browser-console-or-output-window/24128030#24128030) to support the function during Ajax partial postback.

Remember to add a reference to `System.Web.Extension` to support ScriptManager.

```cs
public static class JavaScript
{
    static string scriptTag = "<script type=\"\" language=\"\">{0}</script>";
    public static void ConsoleLog(string message)
    {
        string function = "console.log('{0}');";
        string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);

        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "log", "console.log('" + message + "')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
        }
    }

    public static void ConsoleError(string message)
    {
        string function = "console.error('{0}');";
        string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);

        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "error", "console.error('" + message + "')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
        }
    }

    public static void Alert(string message)
    {
        string function = "alert('{0}');";
        string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);

        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
        }
    }

    static string GenerateCodeFromFunction(string function)
    {
        return string.Format(scriptTag, function);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' –