# Is there a console log for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, console.log

If I have IF statement like below:

```
If currentdate >= rating1  then
    status = 2
ELSEIF currentdate >= rating2  then
    daylight_savings_status = 0
ELSEIF currentdate >= rating3  then
    daylight_savings_status = 1
ELSE 
    daylight_savings_status = 1
End If
```

Is there something like in JavaScript

`console.log('test');`

That I can test on the which IF statement is truth of the statement?

This way I be able to test it in browsers.

Comment: are you asking to log server side code (c#/vb) or front end (Javascript) code in "ASP.Net".

Comment: @snowYetis both would be nice to know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net mvc Console.WriteLine to browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713782/asp-net-mvc-console-writeline-to-browser)

Comment: Or try [ELMAH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441062/how-to-use-elmah-to-manually-log-errors), or [a log4net appender that writes Javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/log4net-log-to-a-javascript-console).

Comment: @CodeCaster yes and no... This could be for ASP.Net Webforms although, the solution is the same.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For Server Side

C# & VB.Net
Server Side - This will show in the Visual Studio Output window.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(log data here)
```

Client Side JavaScript/Jquery - This will show in the browser devtools console window. Works on all popular browsers.

```
console.log(log data here)
```

Comment: And if you want to show the log in the browser devtools, but from a controller .cs file?

Answer (score 13):

I would try to output it to the clients console ONLY If the Console.WriteLine() function doesnt work for you.

```
Page.Response.Write("<script>console.log('" + msg + "');</script>");
```

Ultimately though you should try with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)`

**NB**
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...); gets outputted into the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2008.

Go to menu Debug -> Windows -> Immediate:

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old topic but I've had success with the following:

```
@Html.Raw("<script>console.log('foo bar')</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent for console.log in asp.net is

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 1):

For outputting to your server console, use :

```cs
Console.WriteLine("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a moot point, but I wanted to make a note on this. As @snowYetis answer tells you the correct way to write to the system console for debugging puposes. My "trick" to making this a little more bearable during development is making a helper class somewhere in your project for you to import and use. One of the helper methods I ALWAYS implement in my projects is this one:

```
public void DebugLog(String msg)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

This way you only need to call your `Helper.DebugLog(e.Message);` when you want to log to console without having to dot your way into madness :)

Hope this helps someone