# Why Console.WriteLine in ASP.NET application not writing to file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console.writeline

I was doing some trials on the basis of the following Q&A: [Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net).

The code I tried goes like below:

```
    var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"D:\log.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append);
    var tr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
    Console.SetOut(tr);
    Console.WriteLine("My Default Debugging");
    fs.Close();
```

Here I am setting the `FileStream fs` to `StreamWriter tr` and in turn setting it as `Console.Out` by calling `Console.SetOut()`. So, by that I am expecting it to write to the file by `Console.WriteLine()`. Though my file gets created, it is empty.

What can be the thing I am missing here?

Comment: is the same code working fine in a console application ? and i'll also close write object

Comment: I tried it in a web application. it works if i add `tr.close` before `fs.close` as sekky told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"D:\log.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append);
var tr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
Console.SetOut(tr);
Console.WriteLine("My Default Debugging");
tr.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Maybe it's because you didn't close the StreamWriter before you closed the FileStream?

Answer (score 1):

try `tr.WriteLine("string");` instead.

Comment: It is a good alternative, but my intention was here to make use of `Console.WriteLine` as mentioned in the Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Becuase [`Console.WriteLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) doesn't do that?

> Writes the specified data, **followed by the current line terminator**,
>   to the standard output stream.

Comment: Console.WriteLine() does that and FileStream is a standard output stream.