# .Net Can't Pass View Data to Controller`

Tags: html, .net, view, controller, .net-core

I am attempting to pass data from a view to a controller in my .net application. I want to do this while keeping as much of the original html syntax as possible since it and the corresponding css were imported form adobe muse. I created the following model i am attempting to fill:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am attempting to retrieve the input in the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginBody(LoginModel info)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(email);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(password);

    return View();
}
```

My html is:

```
<form class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu732" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u733-4">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u734-4">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u743-4">
    </div>
    <button class="submit-btn NoWrap clearfix grpelem" id="u744-3" type="submit" value="&nbsp;" tabindex="3">
        <div style="margin-top:-13px;height:13px;">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
     </button>
     <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu749" data-required="true">
          <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u752-4" for="widgetu749_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">PASSWORD:</span></label>
          <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u750-4" placeholder="PASSWORD"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu749_input" name="Password" tabindex="2" /></span>
      </div>
      <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu735" data-required="true">
          <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u738-4" for="widgetu735_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">EMAIL:</span></label>
          <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u737-4" placeholder="EMAIL"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu735_input" name="Email" tabindex="1" /></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

How should I modify my html to be able to receive the input?

Comment: have you tried changing the names to `info.Password` and `info.Email` ?

Comment: @AntonToshik that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change name of your input fields

```
<div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu749" data-required="true">
      <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u752-4" for="widgetu749_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">PASSWORD:</span></label>
      <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u750-4" placeholder="PASSWORD"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu749_input" name="Password" tabindex="2" /></span>
  </div>
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu735" data-required="true">
      <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u738-4" for="widgetu735_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">EMAIL:</span></label>
      <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u737-4" placeholder="EMAIL"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu735_input" name="Email" tabindex="1" /></span>
</div>
```

Console.Write will not work in ASP.NET as it is called using the browser. You can use Debug.Writeline

*[See Stack Overflow question Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)*

Furthermore inorder to access form data

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginBody(LoginModel info)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(info.Email);
    Debug.WriteLine(info.Password);

    return View();
}
```

> Note: Debug.WriteLine only works during debugging.

Comment: I changed my write statements as well as the names of my input fields and it doesn't seem to quite be working. Would you mind taking another look? I edited my code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginBody()
{
    string email = Request["custom_U735"];
    string password = Request["custom_U749"];

return View();
}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HTTP Request'"