# How to capture stdout from a non console ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker

I want to redirect logs to AWSLog driver provided by Docker and which in turns sends logs to AWS Cloud Watch. AWS Log Driver documentation says I need to send logs to STDOUT, but my ASP.NET Application won't work with `Console.WriteLine`. Actually I don't get any compilation error at all, but when I run the command `docker log {ContainerID}` I don't see any logs there that are embedded in `Consoel.WriteLine` statements. Is there any equivalent I can use to STDOUT the logs in non-console .net application.[AWS Docker Log Driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)

Answer (score 0):

Great news, you're probably just looking for the `Out` property which, in turn, exposes a `.WriteLine` method.

`Console.Out.WriteLine("Some log entry");`

For more information about it, here's [the reference on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out) to read.

What it really looks like here is a configuration problem and (technically) a less than ideal choice to log.  You're saying "non console application" but I've definitely just run `Console.WriteLine` in a brand-new ASP.Net WebAPI project and it was fine.  Are you using .net core by any chance?

Finally, I believe the recommended logging for dotnet (especially core?) is through [Microsoft Extensions Logging Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) which means you can depend on an `ILogger` instead of the explicit `Console` implementation.

The `Console.WriteLine` method is definitely *not null* in ASP.Net WebAPI (.Net Framework) but it sounds like you're talking about `Console.Out` being null.

If you really must use `Console.WriteLine` then call `Console.SetOut` with a valid text stream.

```
StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()); 
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true; 
Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

Comment: So a non console application can STDOUT via Console.Out.WriteLine, is there any way to test this out please?

Comment: Yes.  Also, I have to point out, out of the box an ASP.Net WebAPI (not a console app) can _also_ use `Console.WriteLine` without error.  If you edit your question to be a little more specific than "won't work" maybe we can figure out what's really happening in your project.

Comment: I updated my question little bit more. Actually whatever I write in console.writeline in a console application; it is getting picked by the aws log driver. and when I run `docker logs containerId` command I can see all the stuff that I have written in console.writeline. But when I do the same thing in a non console app I don't see any logs at all.

Comment: Turns out Console.WriteLine points to NULL in a non console application. :-|

Comment: Not true in the out-of-the-box asp.net project that I just ran and stepped through.  You're having a configuration problem somewhere.  Updating answer some.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Comment: I am not using core. Also, I am able to put the Console.WriteLine, Question is does it actually puts stuff in STDOUT stream or it just ignores when encountred in non console application.

Comment: It's not so much about the "non console application" as it is whether or not there's anything assigned to `Console.Out` if you read the docs I linked (and the answer _you_ linked) in your configuration.  I'd still recommend the abstraction, but at the worst you can _assign_ the appropriate text stream using `Console.SetOut` at startup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196842/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-clarkitect).