# Dotnet core Web API - read console in debug

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am new to dotnet core.

In Visual Studio, when using debug mode, how can I read the **console** for messages from  `Console.WriteLine("Test Message")`?

Comment: side note: I would recommend looking into ILogger. 
It not only logs into the console but also many other places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studio, look for the button you use to debug (green arrow with "IIS Express" written). In front of "IIS Express" you should see a dropdown arrow. Click on the dropdown and select your app name. Now, when you re-run your project on debug, you will find purple console window popup. Your `Console.WriteLine` should show there.

Answer (score 0):

The console writes to the output window, the one that starts spitting out lines when the project is building when you hit run.

OK! Finally figured it out, it's
`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();`
For asp.net core, from this post
[Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)
I made a new project and got my string to show up in the output window using this line.

Comment: Its not a Console Application, I am building Web API. Is there a way to read the console?

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds my mistake, is what you're doing running in a browser? If so you can right click -> inspect and then click "Console"

Comment: its a backend server build on dotnet core web api.

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds okay, gimme a min

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds do you mean asp.net core?