# How to see the output of console.writeline in Visual Studio 2022 while working with Web APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning ASP.NET Core Web API - currently I am learning the topic of filter. I created a custom filter and I want to print some logs on the console screen to check whether my filter is working or not, but I am not getting any kind of log in the output section.

This is the code for my filter where I am printing something with the help of `Console.Writeline`:

[image: This is the code for my filter where I am printing something with the help of Console.Writeline]

Comment: Web apps run on web servers (even when you are debugging, your machine is playing the role of a web server). Server apps don't have a console.  In part, because servers generally don't have a console. The debugger,  on the other hand, does have a console. Try `Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: i highly recommend you to read this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net

Comment: You may want to reconsider the entire Console usage. Any logging framework would be of much better use. If CommonLogging nuget is used as a proxy, you're able to change logger implementation pretty much whenever you like.

Comment: @Flydog57 using Debug.WriteLine solved my problem.Thank you all for your precious time.